# Find proper Java WebSocket framework generating specific JS code

Tags: java, javascript, frameworks, websocket

Some weeks ago I looked to Java frameworks implementing WebSocket API server side.
I found one that was not one of the best known (jWebSocket etc...) frameworks.

Its specificity was that it was able to generate a specific client JS file implementing the Java described protocol with well formed objects. Something like :

```
var helloSocket = new HelloSocket();
helloSocket.sayHello();
```

Not sure it's exactly like that...

I just can't remember its name ! After 3 hours looking for it again, I just reached stackoverflow one more time :)

PS : Bonus clue, maybe the home page of the project is mainly orange...

Answer (score 0):

Its Java Websockets and its orange: [Kaazing](http://tech.kaazing.com/) perhaps? :)

Comment: Nop, sorry, I should have precised it's certainly opensource... Thanks for the try !

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much of orange there but it's a good one, a Java/JS framework for async web including websockets, long polling and more : [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).

Comment: _Its specificity was that it was able to generate a specific client JS file implementing the Java described protocol with well formed objects. Something like :_
`var helloSocket = new HelloSocket(); helloSocket.sayHello();`
Is it really the case for Atmosphere ?

Comment: It depends on jquery but appart from that, yes you basically create a socket object. It also works with AMD require. It's solid, well documented. I like it.

Comment: Yes, I see it's a solid solution, but I just wanted to look further to my forgotten one... The difference is that the generated JS is specific and has an explicit object model generated by Java code. That what my dumb example tries to express by calling the sayHello method.

Comment: did you check your browser history? :)